# Make enemy go backward

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a space invaders game where the enemy hits the left or right side of the screen it will go down. However, I am struggling to figure out how to do the same thing but in reverse. So when it hits the end of the screen it will move left/right. Here is the code for the enemy.

```
import pygame
import random

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Creates the screen for pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))

#Enemy1
enemy1image = pygame.image.load('Enemy1.png')
enemy1image = pygame.transform.scale(enemy1image, (80, 80))
#Make it appear in a random cordinate
enemy1X = random.randint (0,1000)
enemy1y = random.randint(40,300)
enemy1X_change = 3
enemy1Y_change = 30
enemy1y_change_reverse = -30

def enemy1(x,y):
    #Draws Enemy1 on screen
    screen.blit(enemy1image,(x,y))

#Enemy1 Movement/boundaries
    enemy1X += enemy1X_change
    enemy1(enemy1X, enemy1y)
#Every time the enemy hits the boundary, it moves down
    if enemy1X <= 0:
        enemy1X_change = 4
        enemy1y += enemy1Y_change
    elif enemy1X >= 917:
        enemy1X_change = -4
        enemy1y += enemy1Y_change
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer what is specifically wrong with your code without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your concept appears valid, when you hit the boundary, change direction, move down and increase speed.

Here is an example that creates [sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) that exhibit space-invader style movement. It it a little more effort to create sprites, but they make handling multiple game entities much easier.

```
import pygame
import random

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.init()
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """A block that moves like a space invader"""
    def __init__(self, size, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.image = pygame.Surface([size[0], size[1]])
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color("blueviolet"))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = pos[0]
        self.rect.y = pos[1]
        self.speedx = random.randint(-5, 5)  # note: includes zero
        self.speedy = size[1]  # this only changes on edge collission

    def update(self):
        """move across the screen, skip down a row when at the edge"""
        width, height = screen.get_size()
        if not 0 < self.rect.x < (width - self.size[0]):
            self.speedx *= -1  # reverse direction
            self.rect.y += self.speedy
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.y > (height - self.size[1]):
            self.kill()

# Create some random blocks in random positions
for _ in range(5):
    invader = Block(
        (random.randint(80, 100), random.randint(80, 100)),  # size
        (random.randint(0, 800), random.randint(0, 800)),  # position
    )
    sprite_list.add(invader)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    ## Handle Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # create block on mouse click
            invader = Block((random.randint(80, 100), random.randint(80, 100)), event.pos)
            sprite_list.add(invader)
    ## Clear background
    screen.fill("white")
    ## Update Sprites
    sprite_list.update()
    ## Draw Sprites
    sprite_list.draw(screen)
    ## Update Screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit to 60 FPS
pygame.quit()
```